# Explicitly declaring a function pointer and not a data pointer

Tags: c, visual-c++, function-pointers

I am converting a program from C++ to C, using Microsoft Visual Studio. It's a Windows app, but I don't think that's relevant to this question.

I am using the `/W4` switch to turn on more warning messages. I would like my program to compile with no warnings. The program compiles and runs fine. This is just about warning messages.

Before when the program was C++, it compiled with no warnings, but now that I've converted it to C as best I can, there's a warning that I do not know how to deal with.

Here is the relevant code. The idea is that I'm creating a menu system for a GUI. Each menu contains a collection of menu items, and each menu item contains a function pointer that represents the action that will be performed when the user chooses that menu item.

```
typedef struct MENUITEM
{
    wchar_t* Name;
    void*    Action;
} MENUITEM;

typedef struct MENU
{
    wchar_t*   Name;
    uint8_t    SelectedItem;
    uint8_t    ItemCount;
    MENUITEM** Items;
} MENU;
```

Elsewhere in the program, this the code that handles the event when the user chooses a menu item:

```
void(*FP) (void) = NULL;
FP = (void(*)())MyMenu.Items[MyMenu.SelectedItem]->Action;
FP();
```

Here are the compiler warnings that are generated:

> C4152 nonstandard extension, function/data pointer conversion in expression

And

> C4113 'void (__cdecl *)()' differs in parameter lists from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bacb5038.aspx) for the warning message C4152 states:

> A function pointer is converted to or from a data pointer. This conversion is allowed under Microsoft extensions (/Ze) but not under ANSI C.

OK, so I think this explains why it did not produce a warning as C++, but when compiling as C, it does. But I don't know how to deal with it. To be honest, I did not realize before now that there was a difference between a function pointer and a data pointer.

I cannot figure out how to change the declaration of my function pointer such that it is explicit to the compiler that this is a function pointer, not a data pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `void` in the cast. That's what C4113 is telling you.

You can avoid the cast altogether by declaring `Action` as a function pointer:

```
void (*Action)(void);
```

Comment: Danny_ds's answer was good, but IMO this answer was the best. Now, not only does the code compile without warnings, but it also allowed me to eliminate the extra local FP declaration in my code and use just `MyMenu.Items[MyMenu.SelectedItem]->Action();`

Comment: @RyanRies - Just to be clear: that extra local declaration isn't needed of course - it was there for clarity, to show the usage. Using a typedef for function pointers is usually a good idea.

Comment: @Danny_ds I See. Thank you. Both your answers are valuable. I think both of your answers, when taken in combination, helped it "click" for me. I wish I could accept them both.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need this (with a `typedef`):

```
typedef void(*FP) (void);

typedef struct MENUITEM
{
    wchar_t* Name;
    FP   Action;
} MENUITEM;

int main() {

    MENUITEM it;
    // ... more code

    FP fp = it.Action;
    fp();

    return 0;
}
```